# SQL Query Group By Help

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following data:

```
cust  subject  date
Cust1 Subject1 2010-12-31 21:59:59.000
Cust1 Subject1 2010-12-31 21:59:59.000
Cust4 Subject3 2011-02-27 21:59:59.000
Cust5 Subject1 2010-10-31 21:59:59.000
Cust5 Subject2 2010-10-31 21:59:59.000
Cust6 Subject2 2010-10-31 21:59:59.000
Cust6 Subject2 2010-12-31 21:59:59.000
```

I need to achieve the following:

- Group them by cust and subject
- If there are 2 records with the same cust and subject then i need to return the one with the highest date
- Following the above, if the dates are the same then return only 1 of them.

The result of the query should be:

```
cust  subject  date
Cust1 Subject1 2010-12-31 21:59:59.000
Cust4 Subject3 2011-02-27 21:59:59.000
Cust5 Subject1 2010-10-31 21:59:59.000
Cust5 Subject2 2010-10-31 21:59:59.000
Cust6 Subject2 2010-12-31 21:59:59.000
```

Can anyone help me with this?

I managed to do 2 of the requirements but not all 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ROW_NUMBER() - if you've not used this and the other partitioning functions previously then I can definitely recommend looking into them as they (especially ROW_NUMBER()) have a great deal of uses.

```
SELECT cust, subject, date
FROM (
  SELECT cust, subject, date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust, subject ORDER BY date DESC) AS RN
  FROM <your table>
) SubQuery
WHERE SubQuery.RN = 1
```

Comment: Of course the MAX([date]) works...  ROW_NUMBER() is overkill.  :)  Still, I love it!

Comment: I think you need to add `AS RN` on the row number column for the `WHERE` clause to function correctly...

Comment: Thank you very much.
The reason i accepted this as the answer is that i forgot to mention that i have other columns i need to return as well that i won't include them in the group by and can't use an aggregate function on them (like title for example) and it wouldn't work with the normal group by approach (at least not as easily as this one).
I'll take a look at the partitioning functions, they seem like a big time saver.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT cust, subject, max([date]) FROM myTable GROUP BY cust, subject;
```

You don't really have a column called `date`, do you? `date` is a reserved word which is why it had to be surrounded by square braces in my query above.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cust, subject, max(date) from table group by cust, subject
```